# What Intent is fired after you install an app via a deep link

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

When clicking on a link that leads me to the Play Store to download an app, is that link set anywhere when I first open the app?
If not, where is that information retrievable and how does it work for Deep linking SDKs such as Branch to pass this info for the app's first opening?

My current take on the question would have that info passed onto the Intent's 'data' field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is called `deferred deep linking`:
https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#test-deep-link

When using non-branch deep links, after the application is installed - link data will not be available in the application.
Branch, however, supports this functionality. As long as we are able to match the Branch link click to the app open via our `fingerprint matching` tech.

The data is obtained within the application using our usual method:
https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#read-deep-link

Comment: Props for the `fingerprint matching`  that helped me get that. However, a more in-depth update would be great. 

Answer (score 0):

Fron what I understand you wish to retrieve the data associated with the link when you click on a link and download the app from the Play Store and then open the app.

This is a very basic scenario (called as deferred deep linking) that is achievable with [Branch.io](http://branch.io).

In order to retrieve the link parameters, you need to integrate the Branch SDK into your app. Once integrated correctly, you can read the link parameters of your Branch link in the App.

To learn more you can look at the technical documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/). The Branch API takes care of providing the link information to the app once it is opened via a Branch link.